# Unity Project Settings: What is the difference between "Graphics -> SRP settings" and "Quality -> Rendering -> URP Asset"

Tags: unity, settings

As the title says, I am a bit confused about the aspect that the URP asset is referenced from two different settings:

- "*Project Settings -> Graphics -> SRP settings*"
- "*Project Settings -> Quality -> Rendering -> URP Asset*"

In a blank URP Project, "*Project Settings -> Graphics -> SRP settings*" references the `HighQuality` URP asset, and "*Project Settings -> Quality -> Rendering -> URP Asset*" has three different tiers, all of which reference their respective URP assed (i.e., either `LowQuality`, `MediumQuality`, or `HighQuality`.

Switching from one quality tier to another applies the respective URP asset, i.e., if I switch the quality tier to Low, the `LowQuality` URP asset is applied, even though the `HighQuality` is still set in "*Project Settings -> Graphics -> SRP settings*".

**So now the question: Why do I have to set a URP asset in "*Project Settings -> Graphics -> SRP settings*" if it seems that it is overridden by the URP asset defined in the quality tab?**